# Next and Previous Button to navigate my database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have A "Next" button that when click, will show the first data from my datastore.
I'm stuck to the thing that I want to accomplish, I need to reClick the "Next" Button to show the next data from datastore.
I want to click it over and over again and shows the next data.

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult BtnNext(int current = 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber).Skip(current).Take(1);
            return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
        }
```

View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions 
{ 
         HttpMethod = "GET", 
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
         UpdateTargetId = "current", 
         LoadingElementId = "loading", 
         OnBegin = "ClearResults",
}, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1" })
```

Here is my code for my "Next" button, right now when I click it, it only shows the first data on my datastore. I need to reclick it again to show the next data and so on.

Comment: And how do you invoke that ViewResult? Would be nice to see the actual javascript / markup and how you pass in your `current` integer.

Comment: Im using Ajax button 

    `@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "GET",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "current",
LoadingElementId = "loading",
OnBegin = "ClearResults",
}, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1" })`

Comment: Would you mind adding that to your question?

Comment: sorry @freedomn-m im just a noobie.

Comment: Let me reword that.  You need to pass the `current` value along as the default `int current = 0` is zero so, unless you specify it in the arguments, it will always be zero so you always get the first page.  Easiest option is to turn *off* the default value (`BtnNext(int current)`) and then it will give you an error until it's fixed.

Comment: can you show me how to fix it please.

Comment: what code can I add to make it happen that when I click it again will show the second data from datastore?